# Create multiple instance of Terminator

Tags: terminator

Is there a way to create multiple instance of Terminator , each having its own sets of split terminals. Trying to launch new Terminator instance opens the existing one. The reason I m looking for this is suppose you have two horizontally split terminals and you decide to open another terminal which should look like

```
-----------------
         |       |
         |       |
---------|       |
         |       |
         |       |
-----------------|
```

Comment: [offtopic] No no no no... We had enough of Terminator. Do you want to replicate him, so he can take over the world? :)

Comment: Its possible to create a tab but that tab cannot be detached.

Comment: I never had any problem launching several windows of terminator on Debian 6... Maybe the shortcut you use to start it uses a "flag" which means "Attach to already existing process" or something ?

Comment: ahh that helped me, I m using Gnome3 and I open apps with the super key followed by typing the app name. Little did I know it opens existing app rather than starting new instance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a work around, but it is the best way I've found.

- Open **Terminator**
- Type `terminator &` which runs terminator as a background process
- Type `Ctrl+C` in your original terminator instance to get your command line back

This should result in 2 functioning independent terminator windows. For the split screen layout on start, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/178242) has a good explanation.  Save a layout and then use `terminator -l yourLayout &` for **Step 2** here. It may also be useful to note that `Ctrl+L` will clear the screen, should you desire a clean screen on your original terminator instance.

Answer (score 1):

From a shell, type

"terminator & terminator & terminator &"

and you'll get three instances of terminator.  This is useful say if you have multiple desktops and want one terminator you can move to each one.

Answer (score 1):

Terminator supports launching two windows at once using its "Layout" profiles.

Set up the tabs, splits, and **Windows** that suit your preferences (Windows as in - Open up multiple instances of terminator) then:

- Right click anywhere in a terminator window
- Click `Preferences`
- Click `Layouts`
- There is a list of layouts on the left, yours will likely only contain "default".
- Click `Add` to save your current layout with whatever name you want

  - **OR** to override the default so it launches with this particular layout by default
  - Click `default`, and then click `Save` to override it.
  - The default layout will be updated, but for whatever reason, it will not refresh the configuration displayed for `default` until you close and reopen preferences.

You can configure the internal layouts (Splits, profiles, tabs) of each terminal instance separately, and these will be saved when you save the layout.